# Sidebar at bottomof page, plus code showing on the top of my site

Tags: html, wordpress, header, sidebar

I recently tried to change the header.php file for my site in order to add a click to call button to my site. I successfully added the button, but when you clicked on it, it would overlap with sidebar widgets. I tried putting the code back to how it was, but then the sidebar started displaying on the bottom of the content on my home page. Here is the header code:

```
    <?php // Read functions.php for CSS and JS inclusion ?>
<?php
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT'); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>
<?php
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'qantumpro' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
?>
</title>
<?php
// facebook metadata
if (is_single()){
    echo createMetadata($post->ID); //in frontend_functions.php only for single not archive
}
?>
<?php
    $favicon = get_option( THEME_SHORTNAME . '_favicon');
    if($favicon != ''){
?>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $favicon; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<?php } ?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<?php get_template_part( 'part', 'tracking' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'part', 'custom_styles' ); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>> 

    <?php get_template_part( 'part', 'facebooksdk' ); ?>
    <?php 
    $layoutStyle = get_option(THEME_SHORTNAME.'_boxed_layout');
    if(get_option(THEME_SHORTNAME."_demopanel")=='show' && isset($_COOKIE['cookie'.THEME_SHORTNAME.'_boxed_layout'])){
        if($_COOKIE['cookie'.THEME_SHORTNAME.'_boxed_layout'] != 'Default'){
            $layoutStyle = $_COOKIE['cookie'.THEME_SHORTNAME.'_boxed_layout'];
        }
    }
    if($layoutStyle== 'Unboxed' || $layoutStyle == '' || $layoutStyle == false){
        if(current_user_can('manage_options') || get_option(THEME_SHORTNAME.'_underconstruction_enable')!= 'enable'){   
            get_template_part( 'part', 'topmenu' ); 
         }  ?>
            <div class="qw-topspacer hidden-phone hidden-tablet"></div>
            <?php

    }
    ?>
    <div class="container contentwrapper qw-totalwrapper" id="main_container">
        <?php
            if(get_option(THEME_SHORTNAME.'_underconstruction_enable') == 'enable'){
                if ( current_user_can('manage_options')) { 
                    $alertbox =  '<div class="alert alert-error">
                    <h1>Attention: the "Coming Soon" page is enabled! Only administrators can see the website!!! </h1>
                    <p>Change it in wpadmin > Appearance > QantumThemes Admin Panel > Coming Soon Page</p>
                    </div>';
                    echo $alertbox;

                }else{
                    get_template_part('part','underconstruction');
                }
            }
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'part', 'logobar' ); ?>
        <?php 
            if($layoutStyle== 'Boxed'){
                get_template_part( 'part', 'topmenuboxed' ); 
            }
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'part', 'breadcrumb' ); ?>
        <?php
        if( is_front_page()  && !is_paged() ){
         get_template_part( 'part', 'indexmodules' ); 
        } 
        ?>
```

In addition to this, this text "class="home blog logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support chrome do-etfw">" started showing on the top of my site. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: are you missing a div start at the end of your header?
like :  <div class="site-main"> or something, what theme are you using

Comment: I am using LabelPro2